# On the existence of a globally generated vector bundle on a $K3$ surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is on some confusion on the proof of lemma $1.6$ of the paper titled **Special divisors on curves on a $K3$ surface**(For convenience I am attaching the link  here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389083)

The statement of the lemma is as follows : If $E$ is a vector bundle on a $K3$ surface $X$ which is generated away from finitely many points, then there exists a globally generated vector bundle $F$ on $X$ with $det(F) =det(E)$,$h^{0}(F) \geq  h^{0}(E)$ and $h^{i}(F) =  h^{i}(E)$ for $i \geq 1$.

Sketch of the proof : At the beginning they worked under the hypothesis $H^{0}(E^*)=0$.We then automatically have a short exact sequence of the following form:

$0 \to V \to H^{0}(E) \otimes  \mathcal O_X   \to E \to S_E \to 0$....$(1)$,

where $V$ and $S_E$ are respectively kernel and cokernel of the evaluation map.

**Confusion $1$** : After taking sheaf Hom I got the the short exact sequence $0 \to E^{*} \to  H^{0}(E)^* \otimes  \mathcal O_X \to V^{*} \to \mathcal {E}xt^1(S_E, \mathcal O_X) \to 0$.....$(2)$. But in the paper they got the following exact sequence : $0 \to E^{*} \to  H^{0}(E)^* \otimes  \mathcal O_X \to V^{*} \to  Ext^2(S_E, \mathcal O_X) \to 0$...$(3)$.But, I don't see how $Ext^2(S_E, \mathcal O_X)$ is there in the S.E.S $(3)$.Is there a way to connect the terms $\mathcal{E}xt^1(S_E,\mathcal O_X)$and  $Ext^2(S_E, \mathcal O_X)$?

At this point starting from S.E.S $(2)$ looking at this long cohomology sequence I got,$0 \to H^{0}(E)^* \to H^{0}(V^*) \to H^{0}(R_E) \to 0$, where $R_E := \mathcal {E}xt^1(S_E, \mathcal O_X)$.

Then in the paper it's stated that we may thus choose a subspace $W \subset H^{0}(V^*)$ such that $0 \to H^{0}(E)^* \to W  \to H^{0}(R_E) \to 0$ and $W$ generates $V^*$ as a vector bundle (i.e the evaluation map  $ W \otimes \mathcal O_X \to V^*$ is surjective)

**Doubt 1:** I can see only two candidates for $W$ namely  $ H^{0}(E)^* ,H^{0}(V^*) $.But in any case the evaluation maps are evidently  not surjective. So what ensures existence of such a $W$?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: How did you get your `short' (wrong terminology) exact sequence in conlcusion1? Split (1) into short exact sequences (only three terms, not four) and work from there.

Comment: @Mohan,If we denote the evaluation map by $f$,then we can have a short exact sequence from $(1)$  as $0 \to V \to H^{0}(E) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to Imf \to 0$ which gives us $ 0 \to \mathcal{H}om(Imf , \mathcal O_X) \to (H^{0}(E))^* \otimes \mathcal O_X \to V^* \to \mathcal {E}xt^1(Imf, \mathcal O_X) \to 0$...(A) .Also we can have another short exact sequence from $(1)$ as  $ 0 \to (H^{0}(E) \otimes \mathcal O_X )/V \to E \to S_E \to 0$ which gives us $0 \to \mathcal{H}om((H^{0}(E) \otimes \mathcal O_X) /V, \mathcal O_X) \to \mathcal {E}xt^1(S_E, \mathcal O_X) \to 0$...(B). How (A) & (B)  ->2

Comment: I do not understand the last line, where did $E^*$ on the left go? Also, why use two expressions, $\mathrm{Im} f$ and $H^0(E)\otimes\mathcal{O}_X/V$ for the same thing? Can you go a little further to see that $\mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathrm{Im} f,\mathcal{O_X})=\mathcal{E}xt^2(S_E,\mathcal{O}_X)$?

Comment: @Mohan,yes I forgot to write  $E^*$ in the last exact sequence

Comment: Can we say that $\mathcal {E}xt^1(S_E, \mathcal O_X) =0$ because $1 < codim(S_E) =2$,then from short exact sequence (B) we have $E^* \cong  \mathcal{H}om(Imf , \mathcal O_X)$?

Comment: @Mohan, If we take  $\mathcal {E}xt$ to the exact sequence $0 \to Im(f) \to E \to E/Im(f) \to 0$ we get $\mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathrm{Im} f,\mathcal{O_X})=\mathcal{E}xt^2(S_E,\mathcal{O}_X)$.Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @Mohan,Is it so that in the paper when it's written Ext it's actually meant $\mathcal {E}xt$?.For instance we got $R_E = \mathcal {E}xt^2(S_E , \mathcal O_X)$, but in the paper it's mentioned that $R_E = Ext^2(S_E , \mathcal O_X)$.

Comment: And does the following two facts make sense? $(1)$ we can take $W = H^{0}((H^{0}(E))^* \otimes \mathcal O_X)/E^*)$ and $(2)$  $H^{1}((H^{0}(E))^* \otimes \mathcal O_X)/E^*) =0$,but I don't see why this first cohomology vanish.Does it have anything to do with the sheaf in consideration being supported on a finite set of points(?) and hence flasque?

Comment: Also is it true that $H^1(E^*) =H^0(R_E)$ ?